# A simple calculation in Peskin's and Schroeder's QFT book on page 608 chapter 18

Tags: mathematics, lie-algebra

I am trying to calculate the term:
$$(t^a)_{ij} (t^a)_{kl}$$

In the book it's written that it equals to 
$$A\delta_{il}\delta_{kj}+B\delta_{ij}\delta_{kl}$$
and from using equation (18.40)
$$tr[t^a](t^a)_{kl}=0$$
$$(t^a t^a)_{il}=4/3 \delta_{il}$$
we get:
$$(t^a)_{ij}(t^a)_{kl}=1/2(\delta_{il}\delta_{kj}-1/3 \delta_{ij}\delta_{kl})$$

Now, I tried to prove the last equality, but I am not sure how to continue, we have:
For $k=l, i=j , i\ne l, k\ne j$: $B= (t^a)_{jj}(t^a)_{ll}$.
and for $i=l, k=j , i\ne j , k\ne l$ $A= (t^a)_{lj}(t^a)_{jl}$.

And as far as I can tell there's no summation convention here, am I right?

So how to get eq. (18.41) in the book?

Comment: Which one is 18.41?

Comment: both $$tr[t^a](t^a)_{kl}=0$$
$$(t^a t^a)_{il}=4/3 \delta_{il}$$ are eq. (18.40) in the book.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is summation convention used in those formulae. In particular they are all summed over all values of $a$.

Using summation convention on both $a$ and other repeating indices:
\begin{align}
tr[t^a](t^a)_{kl} & = (t^a)_{ii} (t^a)_{kl} = 0, \\
(t^a)_{ii} (t^a)_{kl} & = A \delta_{il} \delta_{ki} + B \delta_{ii} \delta_{kl} =
  A \delta_{kl} + 3 B \delta_{kl} = 0.
\end{align}
Therefore:
\begin{align}
A = -3 B.
\end{align}

For the second constraint:
\begin{align}
(t^a)_{ij} (t^a)_{jl} = A \delta_{il} \delta_{jj} + B \delta_{ij} \delta_{jl} =
  3 A \delta_{il} + B \delta_{il} = \frac{4}{3} \delta_{il},
\end{align}
or:
\begin{align}
3A + B & = \frac{4}{3}.
\end{align}

Solving the system of equations we get $A = \frac{1}{2}$, $B = -\frac{1}{6}$.